# How to create listview.xml listview inside main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, listactivity

I want to create only one main.xml file that contains listview and others( such as textview ....)
And listview (contains music list) should come up inside the main.xml
All example that I saw is always creates two xml file one is main and the other is listview.

Comment: so its will be simple list view or custom ?

Comment: can you please tell in detail?

Comment: hey its simple you have to make custome listview.in your main xml ,put the listview and make another rowfile xml and put the textview.then u have to extends base adapter.many example are there on goolge..try it..

you can refer this link for ref.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @google on your posted link she used two or more xml files.
I want to make only one main.xml file and listview(music list) should live inside main.xml,,, Also I did not get your comment clearly sorry for this.:) Can  you explain in detail if possible post some example code??